# Terminal: Does not use files in correct sequence

Tags: command-line

I run Xubuntu 16.10, the Yakkety Yak version. I just tried to use `align_image_stack` to align a sequence of photographs. I wrote a command like

```
align_image_stack -a aligned -v -c 20
```

And after that, I just selected the JPG files with the mouse, and shove them all into the Terminal window. So, the names of these JPG files are appended after the command.

When I move all 37 files into the terminal window, the full command has the file names in the correct order - but `align_image_stack` begins processing with `IMG_867.JPG` and `IMG_0858.JPG`, not `IMG_0839.JPG` and `IMG_0840.JPG`.

Does the console have a glitch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man align_image_stack`:

```
--use-given-order
    Use the image order as given on the command line.  (By default images
    will be sorted by exposure values.)
```

So you need the `--use-given-order` flag.